# HP RX6600 - Possible Processor carrier board failure

Tags: hp, central-processing-unit, hp-ux

So there is an HP Integrity RX6600 server, which simply cannot be turned on. When user power-on the chassis, It'll be hanged at POST process and cannot reach EFI and booting OS.

After reviewing logs (MP logs) that I'll share here, our first guess was the fault on Processor Carrier Board or its CPU Modules:

```
Log Entry 64: 09 Aug 2017 19:19:48
Alert Level 7: Fatal
Keyword: BOOT_NOT_DETECTED
No events were received from system firmware
Logged by: Baseboard Management Controller;
Sensor: Processor 
Data1: FRB2/Hang in POST failure
0x20598B6054020430 FFFF036F00070300

Log Entry 107: 09 Aug 2017 20:34:16
Alert Level 7: Fatal
Keyword: MISSING_FRU_DEVICE
Missing FRU device - Processor 0
Logged by: Baseboard Management Controller;
Sensor: Entity Presence - Missing Device
0x20598B71C8020700 FF20807115250300
```

Basically there are 2 CPU Modules installed on the CPU Board. so we applied for second handed materials for both CPU Modules and CPU Board. However after installing new parts on server we pretty much faced same problem, which means the server still cannot detect Processor 0 and therefore POST process cannot be completed. We did several test-cases with newly installed parts:

1- Removed the CPU Module from Slot0 and powered-on: It'll be failed, we receive same alerts, plus when we query about processor status:

```
Slot0: Installed and Not configured
Slot1: Installed and configured
```

Which I found this abnormal, because there is no CPU at Slot0

2- We swapped the working CPU at Slot1 to Slot0: It'll be failed, we receive same alerts, plus when we query about processor status:

```
Slot0: Installed and Not configured
Slot1: Not installed
```

Has anyone experience such issue ? Is there anything else I could check for troubleshooting ? Based on testcase result, could we conclude that maybe even the newly purchased CPU Board is faulty ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, apparently the CPU Board was faulty. we've replaced with another one and everything good now. :)